# Laravel attach object to many objects in many-to-many relationship without loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a many-to-many relationship on a User model and Notification model.

To create a Notification and attach to many Users, I am currently doing:

```
$users = User::all();
$notification = new Notification(['title'=>'some title', 'body'=>'notification body']);
$notification->save();
foreach ($users as $user) {
   $user->notifications()->attach([$notification->id]);
}
```

The foreach implementation won't be ideal if `$users->count()` becomes a very large number; 
Please is there a better way to get this done without so many loops?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

You can pass an array of ids to the `attach()` method like so:

```
$user_ids = User::pluck('id');
$notification = new Notification(['title'=>'some title', 'body'=>'notification body']);
$notification->save();
$notification->users()->attach($user_ids);
```

Assuming your relationship on `$notification` is called `users()` of course

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, not using Eloquent.

There exists the ability to `attach` multiple records simultaneously, but this internally uses a loop itself, so you're not making any saving there.

```
$notification->users()->attach([
    1 => [],
    2 => [],
    // ...
]);
```

When dealing with large result sets, Eloquent is not necessarily the ideal solution. You might consider using the Database query builder or even raw SQL to handle mass insert operations.

Comment: I appreciate the in-dept explanation. I never had any idea Eloquent uses a loop for this. I always thought it was done via some SQL mass insert query.

Comment: It’s always worthwhile to look through the source code. Or can learn a lot about how something works. In this case look for the `formatAttachRecords` method in [this file](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php). I’m on my phone so can’t link to the exact line number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = User::all();

$notification = Notification::create([
    'title'=>'some title', 
    'body'=>'notification body'
]);

$notification->user()->attach($users);
```